# Card Layout Java Application Won't show anything

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I am trying to make a card based application. I've been trying to follow tutorials and such. Here is my code. So far its very simple. The window shows up but the textpane inside does not.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package professorphysinstall;

/**
*
* @author Kyle
*/

//Imports
  import java.awt.CardLayout;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JTextPane;

  public class ProfessorPhysInstall {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //Variables
    JFrame mainframe = new JFrame();
    mainframe.setSize(500, 435);
    JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    mainframe.setTitle("Future Retro Gaming Launcher");
    //Screen1
    JPanel screen1 = new JPanel();
    JTextPane TextPaneScreen1 = new JTextPane();
    TextPaneScreen1.setEditable(false);
    TextPaneScreen1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
    TextPaneScreen1.setText("Welcome to the install wizard  for Professor Phys!\n\nPlease agree to the following terms and click the next button to continue.");
    TextPaneScreen1.setSize(358, 48);
    TextPaneScreen1.setLocation(0, 0);
    screen1.add(TextPaneScreen1);
    mainframe.add(cards);
    mainframe.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `JPanel` containing the `JTextPane`, `screen1`, to the `CardLayout` container `cards`:

```
cards.add(screen1, "TextPane Card");
```

Aside: Java naming concentions show that variables start with a *lowercase* letter such as `textPaneScreen1`.

Comment: Oh right duh. Thanks very much!

Comment: By any chance would you know how to add a border but with a little bit of space? It tried changing the margin to 3 but that didn't move the border at all.

Comment: Youre giving me very little to go on here. What type of border? What did you try & what didnt work. Probably better as a new question

Comment: Sure I will make a new question now.